# Как в IDEA выполнить поиск куска кода по всему проекту?

Tags: intellij-idea

Например, я хочу найти все места, где используется:

```
log.info
```

Перехожу в поиск, а мне какую-то дичь возвращает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Это вы используете меню `Navigate`. Эта функция используется, чтоб искать файлы или классы или переменные/функции *по имени*.

Полнотекстовый поиск *по содержимому* находится в `Edit -> Find -> Find in Path`.

[image: intellj idea find in path]

Comment: Наверное, имели в виду - Find in Files (shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F)

Comment: Если это вопрос ко мне, то нет. У меня и в Intellij CE и в Intellij 2014 этот пункт меню называется именно `Find in Path`. Горячая клавиша точно зависит от ОС, возможно, пункт меню в новых версиях переименовали.